# An error occurred when trying to create a controller, Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api

I am getting the below error on an inconsistent basis when calling a specific method on my controller:

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'TimelineController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

The confusing part is that this method does occasionally work, and that the controller itself does have a parameterless constructor. Here's a brief example of the code:

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/timeline")]
public class TimelineController : CherishApiController
{
    private readonly TimelineEventRepository _timelineEventRepository;
    private readonly BlobHelper _blobHelper;
    private readonly ChildHelper _childHelper;
    private readonly AccountHelper _accountHelper;

    public TimelineController()
    {
        _timelineEventRepository = new TimelineEventRepository();
        _blobHelper = new BlobHelper();
        _childHelper = new ChildHelper();
        _accountHelper = new AccountHelper();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("UploadImage")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(UploadMediaResponse))]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadImage()
    {
        try
        {
            return await Upload(Request.Content, MediaType.Image);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ErrorResponse(ex);
        }
    }

    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Upload(HttpContent requestContent, string mediaType)
    {
        // reads the data from the multi-part request and stores a record in an Azure DocumentDB
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm not using any form of dependency injection (as this is a small non-essential web-app) and pretty much all of the solutions I've seen when researching are involving a DI setup issue.

Here is the full stack trace if it helps:

```
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'TimelineController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"  
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n  
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"One or more errors occurred.","ExceptionType":"System.AggregateException","StackTrace":"
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)\r\n
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQuery`1.GetEnumerator()\r\n
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n
   at Cherish.Domain.Repositories.Implementation.DocumentRepository`1.ReadOrCreateDatabase()\r\n
   at Cherish.Domain.Repositories.Implementation.DocumentRepository`1..ctor()\r\n
   at lambda_method(Closure )\r\n
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An error occurred while sending the request.","ExceptionType":"System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException","StackTrace":"
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryExecutionContext.<ExecuteAllAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQuery`1.<GetEnumeratorTAsync>d__10.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Unable to connect to the remote server","ExceptionType":"System.Net.WebException","StackTrace":"
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions","ExceptionType":"System.Net.Sockets.SocketException","StackTrace":"
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)\r\n
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalBind(EndPoint localEP)\r\n
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean flowContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)\r\n
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UnsafeBeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)\r\n
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)"}}}}}
```

Can anyone guide me on what the issue is?

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone guide me on what the issue is?

Sure

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'TimelineController'.

This is the actual error. The ControllerFactory was unable to create the controller.

> Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

This is just a helpful message because most of the time for non-depedency-injected controllers this is the issue.

You constructor creates 4 objects (Looks like a good case to use Dependency Injection).

```
_timelineEventRepository = new TimelineEventRepository();
_blobHelper = new BlobHelper();
_childHelper = new ChildHelper();
_accountHelper = new AccountHelper();
```

You can simply comment them all out and it should "work" creating the controller.  Obvious the method call will break, but that would prove one of these is the issue.  If I were to guess, I'd say the `TimelineEventRepository()` is the culpret. Which everone is causing the issue you should be able to debug it in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I commented those lines from the constructor, and added `IDisposable` implementation to the repository so that I could wrap every usage in a `using()`. Unfortunately I'm still encountering the same problem.